# Why does setPadding(getPadding()) change look of JavaFX buttons?

Tags: button, javafx

I have a bunch of custom buttons that extend JavaFX Button. They look like this:

[image: Regular buttons]

I have added this line in the constructor:

```
setPadding(Insets.EMPTY);
```

And buttons changed their look:

[image: Altered buttons]

I wanted to change only left and right padding, so I wanted to find out what original values were. I've placed a breakpoint in the constructor (before `setPadding`) and ran `getPadding()` in a debugger. To my surprise, the result was `0, 0, 0, 0` - that is `Insets.EMPTY`.

So I ran an experiment - I've changed previously added line to this:

```
setPadding(getPadding());
```

And buttons lost padding, even though insets shouldn't have changed. How can it be explained?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that initial padding isn't applied in constructor, but later - unless you have overridden it in code.

Padding is stored in a `StyleableObjectProperty<Insets>`. Notably, this class provides a [`getStyleOrigin()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/css/StyleableObjectProperty.html#getStyleOrigin--) method:

> `public StyleOrigin getStyleOrigin()`
>
> Tells the origin of the value of the property. This is needed to determine whether or not CSS can override the value.

I found it out by checking not just value returned by `Button.getPadding()`, but also `Button.paddingProperty()`. I've noticed that the property actually changes when `setPadding()` is called - its private `origin` field changes from `NULL` to `USER`.

According to the JavaDoc I've cited above, values from CSS styles will not be applied if they are already set from code. If the origin is `NULL`, it's later replaced with default values from CSS theme. `setPadding(getPadding())` doesn't change property's value, but changes its origin, so CSS can't override the value later.

Comment: And consequently, the way to get the actual effect you want is to replace the padding settings with your own in an external stylesheet. The [default padding](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/openjfx/8u60/rt/file/996511a322b7/modules/controls/src/main/resources/com/sun/javafx/scene/control/skin/modena/modena.css) is `-fx-padding: 0.333333em 0.666667em 0.333333em 0.666667em; `.